# Report on Parent with two Children

Tags: reporting, joined-reports

I haven't found a clear answer on this: is it possible to create a nice report of one parent object with multiple children?

I've been able to achieve a report that can filter (with cross-object filters) on one of the children, but I can only see fields from the other.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I named this the "inverted V" and it's a tough report scenario.

Check out joined reports--it's two reports side by side, joined by a common field (in your case, on the parent).

Comment: Thanks Shane, this seems to be working so far, even if it's a bit clunky :)